# Invalid combination of opcodes and operands when cmov pointer and register

Tags: assembly

I want to write a piece of code in assembly language, that would change all uppercase characters in a string to lowercase. However, I would like to avoid as many conditional jumps as possible. I tried the following code:

```
    global tolower_cmov

tolower_cmov:
    enter 0, 0
    mov edx, [ebp + 8]
    xor eax, eax
    xor ecx, ecx
.back:
    test [edx], byte 0xff
    jz .end

    mov eax, [edx]
    mov ecx, [edx]
    add [eax], byte 'a' - 'A'
    cmp [edx], byte 'A'
    cmovb [edx], eax
    cmp [edx], byte 'z'
    cmova [edx],  ecx

    inc edx
    jmp .back
.end:
    leave
    ret
```

But NASM gives me `Invalid combination of opcodes and operands` error on both CMOV lines... I don't understand, what is wrong with those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1524450/michael), I have managed to find a solution, that suits my needs:

```
    global tolower_cmov

tolower_cmov:
    enter 0, 0
    mov edx, [ebp + 8]
.back:
    test [edx], byte 0xff
    jz .end

    xor eax, eax
    xor ecx, ecx

    mov eax, [edx]
    mov ecx, [edx]
    add ecx, dword 'a' - 'A'
    cmp [edx], byte 'A'
    cmovb ecx, eax
    cmp [edx], byte 'Z'
    cmova ecx, eax
    mov [edx], ecx

    inc edx
    jmp .back
.end:
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: Perhaps you've solved the use of `CMOVxx` but your program is still very wrong! You iterate through the string byte per byte (`inc edx`), but on each iteration you destroy the 3 following bytes because you wrote `mov [edx],ecx`. Learn to use __byte sized registers where appropriate__

Comment: Will calling `mov [edx], cl` fix the problem?

Comment: @Storm Writing `mov [edx],cl` will indeed fix the problem, but I bet you that user @Fifoernik also meant you should write: `mov al, [edx]` `mov cl,[edx]` `add cl, byte 'a' - 'A'` (Other solutions exist...)

Comment: Do all the comparing / `cmov`ing in registers, *then* store it back into the string (unconditionally).  Also, do your end-of-string check on the byte after loading it into a register.  And instead of loading twice, into al and cl, just load al and `mov cl, al`.

Answer (score 4):

From the description o `CMOVcc — Conditional Move` in Intel's manual:

> These instructions can move 16-bit, 32-bit or 64-bit values from memory to a general-purpose register or from one
>   general-purpose register to another.

So you can do e.g. `cmovb eax, [edx]` or `cmovb edx, eax`, but not `cmovb [edx], eax`.

I couldn't make much sense of your code in general. It seems like `edx` contains the address of your string. But then you read a DWORD from that address (`mov eax, [edx]`), i.e. you read 4 characters from the string, and then try to use those 4 characters as an address in `add [eax], byte 'a' - 'A'`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are working with UniCode strings of 16-bit length or above, [CMOV](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CMOVcc.html) is suboptimal for your case, because the destination has to be a r16/r32/r64. So choosing a `BYTE` memory operand as target is not possible and would result in an `Invalid combination of opcodes and operands` error. The only possibility would be to choose a 16 or 32 or 64 bit register as a destination and then copying the lowest byte with another `MOV' operation to the memory destination.

```
0F 47 /r            CMOVA r16, r/m16    RM  Valid   Valid   Move if above (CF=0 and ZF=0).  
0F 47 /r            CMOVA r32, r/m32    RM  Valid   Valid   Move if above (CF=0 and ZF=0).  
REX.W + 0F 47 /r    CMOVA r64, r/m64    RM  Valid   N.E.    Move if above (CF=0 and ZF=0).
```

But I suggest you an easy way to convert a string to lower case using the fact that in the ASCII tables lower and uppercase letters differ only in bit 5 (=0x20).

```
global tolower_cmov

tolower_cmov:
    enter 0, 0
    mov edx, [ebp + 8]

.back:
    test byte ptr [edx], 0xff
    jz .end
    or byte ptr [edx], 0x20
    inc edx
    jmp .back

    inc edx
    jmp .back
.end:
    leave  
    ret
```

P.S.: This code depends on treating characters(a-z,A-Z) only. Otherwise you'd have to put a range check before the `OR` opcode.

Comment: Why not remove the extra `inc edx` `jmp .back` ?

Comment: To exit processing the ASCIIZ string you need to `TEST` the byte with 0xFF in stead of `CMP` it!

Comment: @Sep Roland: Thanks, I fixed it. It was a copy/paste error from my different test code. The questioner had it right already.

Comment: I would have done a byte-load, tested it for zero, ORed it with 0x20, and stored it back.  This has test with a memory operand, and a read-modify-write `OR`.  The OP's do-everything-with-memory-operands idea is something that should also be corrected.  Also, he could easily have used `cmov` by doing `movzx` loads.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Thanks for your elaboration. I had this in my first version and then edited it for brevity/less opcodes. My preferred version would just use `XLAT` (unfortunately not implemented well on current archs, so should be replaced later by `movzx eax, byte ptr [ebx+eax]` or something like that) with a 256 byte table. Seems overkill for this case, but useful in more general ones.

Comment: If you xor-zero eax, then you can avoid partial-register stalls from writing `al` and then doing `mov al, [ebx+eax]`.  So spending transistors on `xlat` doesn't make much sense when it's easy to emulate.  If code-size matters more than speed, it's not *that* slow.  `xlat` used to be 2 uops on pre-SnB, so it was basically the same as running `movzx eax, al` / `mov al, [ebx+al]`, but without actually modifying the upper 24b of eax.  IDK why it got worse, and IDK why it only has one per 2c throughput on Intel and AMD.